# Wired Internet abruptly stopped working Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ethernet

My Ethernet just stopped working after I might have probably messed up with some of the settings.

I have a dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu. Internet works fine on windows 8, and used for for ubuntu too.
But sometimes it did't.

so I did as instructed here.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6129/why-does-my-ethernet-port-sometimes-not-work

and a few other links.

I am using a static IP provided by my institute and it's own DNS servers

My bash history is this:
Note: The sudo dhclient eht0 doesn't show anything in my case i had to terminate using ctrl+c everytime.

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
ubuntu-bug -p network-manager

sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
sudo modprobe -r r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169
sudo dhclient eth0
ubuntu-bug -p linux
sudo service network-manager start

sudo lshw -C network
sudo ifup eth0 
ifconfig -a
cat /etc/resolv.conf

sudo service network-manager stop 
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
sudo service network-manager start
```

---

### After sometime I used these commands

```
sudo dhclient eth0
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start

route -n
nano /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces 
ifconfig
lspci |grep Ethernet
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
lshw -C network
rfkill list
sudo ethtool eth0
lsmod
```

---

### After searching everywhere and ethernet stopping now i used the following

```
sudo modprobe -rfv 8139cp 8139too
sudo modprobe -v 8139too
sudo depmod -a 
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I didn't change any of the files I guess.
After I started today using my ethernet, I was 
 being shown two connections for the first time: Auto Ethernet
I never saw Auto Ethernet before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record.
My machine was a HP ENVY 15-j110tx laptop.

I couldn't find the solution so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu which solved the problem.

Comment: Well, that's not the solution.